# Mechanize with weird https form RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize-ruby

I'm using RoR trying to search a simple form at my college using **mechanize**. The code works fine for searching google, but returns the search form in the results? I'm really confused. Any advice? Thanks!

```
ruby script/console
require 'mechanize'
agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
agent.get("https://www.owens.edu/cgi-bin/class.pl/")
agent.page.forms
form = agent.page.forms.last
form.occ_subject = "chm"
form.submit
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me. What problem are you having? Also, you're going to get a lot of test data if you leave a complete script that submits data on your SO post. But that might not be bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it! When `form.submit` is being called, it is assuming the last button in `form.buttons` is the button to use. The last button in `form.buttons` is for the advanced form, hence the resulting page object being another form, albeit the more comprehensive advanced search form.

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
agent.get("https://www.owens.edu/cgi-bin/class.pl/")
agent.page.forms
form = agent.page.forms.last
form.occ_subject = "chm"
result = agent.submit(form, form.buttons.first)

result.parser.css('table.cs-table-settings tr.tbl-class-fill-b td font b').map { |v| v.text.strip }

=> ["Principles of Chemistry", "Principles of Chemistry", "Principles of Chemistry", "Principles of Chemistry", …]
```

Finally we get to the bottom of it! The HTML is horrible, so you will need to put your XPath hat on for this one! :)

Comment: Awesome! I thought it was a button issue. I might now be able to program my boss out of a job - or at least save the poor guy some time for other things.